# Summarize which event came first

Tags: stata

I have panel data of individuals, their marital status (0 = not married, 1 = married) and one random shock (0 = No shock, 1 = Shock). Now for the people who experience the shock (Everyone except id1), I would like to know which person was already married when they experienced the shock (n=2, id3, id5), who was not married when they experienced the shock but subsequently got married (n=1, id2) and who was not married when they experienced the shock and did not get married subsequently (n=1, id4).

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int year str3 id float(shock maritalstatus)
2010 "id1" 0 1
2011 "id1" 0 1
2012 "id1" 0 1
2013 "id1" 0 0
2014 "id1" 0 0
2015 "id1" 0 0
2010 "id2" 1 0
2011 "id2" 0 1
2012 "id2" 0 1
2013 "id2" 0 1
2014 "id2" 0 1
2015 "id2" 0 1
2010 "id3" 0 1
2011 "id3" 0 1
2012 "id3" 0 1
2013 "id3" 1 1
2014 "id3" 0 1
2015 "id3" 0 1
2010 "id4" 1 0
2011 "id4" 0 0
2012 "id4" 0 0
2013 "id4" 0 0
2014 "id4" 0 0
2015 "id4" 0 0
2010 "id5" 0 1
2011 "id5" 0 1
2012 "id5" 1 1
2013 "id5" 0 1
2014 "id5" 0 1
2015 "id5" 0 1
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the data example.

Being married when the shock arrived is identifiable by looking at each observation, but the trick lies in spreading that to all observations for the same identifier.

```
egen married_at_shock = total(marital == 1 & shock == 1), by(id)
```

The next variable is a variation on the same theme.

```
egen not_married_at_shock = total(marital == 0 & shock == 1), by(id)
```

The last variable seems harder to me. I think you have to work out explicitly when the shock occurred

```
egen when_shock = mean(cond(shock == 1, year, .)), by(id)
```

and then check what happened afterwards

```
egen never_married_after_shock = total(marital & year > when_shock), by(id)

replace never_married_after_shock = never_married == 0 if when_shock < . 

tabdisp id, c(*married*)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       id |     married_at_shock  not_married_at_shock  never_married_afte~k
----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
      id1 |                    0                     0                     0
      id2 |                    0                     1                     0
      id3 |                    1                     0                     0
      id4 |                    0                     1                     1
      id5 |                    1                     0                     0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are no doubt other ways to approach this.

Any reading list starts with underlining that true and false conditions yield 1 and 0 respectively

[as discussed in this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/)

which has many applications

[such as applications to "any" and "all" questions, which include "ever" and "never"](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/)

The use of `egen` as a workhorse here is natural given your need to work both on observations for each identifier and over each history. Some tricks are covered in

[this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055).